# cannot mount remote partition using fstab/fuse

Tags: ubuntu, mount, fstab, fuse

Using a combination of http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2007/01/02/mount-remote-directories-securely-with-ssh-ubuntu-6061-610/ and http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fstab.html I figured I could mount the root of another computer to somewhere on my new laptop to make it easier to transfer files and stuff.

Now, I can connect through SSH and browser the files through an ad-hoc mount - but I would like to be able to do this automatically, and so had a look at fstab.

my new entry in fstab is:

```
remote_comp:/        /var/remote_comp     fuse    defaults       0        0
```

but testing with mount -a results in the following error:

```
/bin/sh: remote_comp:/: not found
```

I thought the problem was because I was trying to mount the root of the other computer, but even trying sub-directories result in the same error message.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should use a folder like /mnt/remote OR /media/remote. /var is NOT for that purpose, you should leave it as it is.

Second, fstab should look like this:
`sshfs#user@domain.org:/home/user  /media/user   fuse    defaults,allow_other    0  0`
OR
`sshfs#llib@192.168.1.200:/home/llib/FAH /media/FAH2 fuse defaults 0 0`
(Example is from the [Arch howto](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sshfs).)

Comment: still problematic - it requested a password and then permissions were messed up... i'm just going to use the Gnome GUI options as they work fine

Comment: You could also write the line into /etc/rc.local. It will be executed at every boot and will mount the stuff if you give all the commands/permissions as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply go with

```
#!/bin/sh

sshfs user@hostname:/path/to/folder /local/folder
```

and then put it in /etc/inittab